# How to turn zed board into a usb gadget at a u-boot stage

Tags: usb, xilinx, u-boot

I am using zed board, and I am beginner to u-boot drivers. I have downloaded xilinx u-boot source code. I am able to turn it into usb host mode.

I have tried to turn host mode into peripheral mode by modifying device tree "zynq-zed.dts". But it is not being affected.

How to turn zed board into a gadget in a u-boot stage.

Answer (score 0):

U-boot supports ums command for using board as usb mass storage device.